# My ubuntu terminal is frozen and I can't bring it back after installing ng-comman

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I installed this ng-commom and used the command script output.txt to save my terminal output to a file, but immediately after that my terminal froze. I have restarted the machine, turned off, and nothing seems to bring the terminal back.

It's like this, forever. I can't type anything, CTRL+C doesn't work, nor does CTRL+Q, nothing works... I don't know what else to do:

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; only tagged Kubuntu which limits what we can do. I don't see a `ng-comman` package anyway in repositories; maybe you meant `ng-common` but being specific allows us to understand & provide meaningful advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.